# Using Linkedin API, how can I get the user's profile statistics or activity?

Tags: linkedin-api

I want to show's the user their activity & statistics of their profile.

But unfortunately, I couldn't find any API endpoint related to this data on LinkedIn API documentation.

Thank you.

I tried on this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/

Answer (score 0):

The [Compliance APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/compliance/?view=li-lms-unversioned) may provide what you're looking for, at least in terms of activity.